# Cannot type in Unity Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't type in the Unity inspector or rename any object. I tried clicking in many different areas recommended from the web. Note that this is not an error, but something I simply can't do. Is there any settings I need to turn on or off?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: 2019.4. Unity says it's up to date.

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean exactly .. could you add a screenshot of what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this:

#### Solution A

Go to layout then set the layout to default, it's like resetting the unity.

#### Solution B

Restart unity, just Close the Unity editor and open the project again.

Hopefully, one of these helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `EditorWindow` as a reference class, try using:

```
string name;
void  OnGUI()
{
name = EditorGUILayout.TextField("GameObjectName", name);
}
```